# Calculate the last digit of $a^{b^c}$

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I'm doing some programming challenges, and I have to find the last digit of the result from evaluating the expression $a^{b^c}$. The unit tests of this challenge feature very big integers, so calculating the result of this is out of question, the program will crash without a doubt.

So my question is, is there a way to simplify such an expression so I can solve it with the integers given as test inputs, or is there an obvious way to calculate the last digit of the result based on the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ ?

Comment: Since I'm getting downvoted I guess I did something wrong, feel free to explain what wrong I did so I won't do it again ?

Comment: I edited the tags, is that enough of a hint?

Comment: I have no idea what modular arithmetic is, but thank you, if it's clearer this way

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but the reason people downvote on math.stackexchange is when questions show a lack of research effort. Could you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Jam I tried to look up on Google/Wikipedia/... on theorems that would allow me to simplify such an expression. Without success, maybe because it's really hard to look up for specific things when you don't have the technical term behind it (e.g. modular arithmetic ?). And looking for "a^b^c" doesn't help at all, since Google seems to ignores the ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k$ be the last digit of $a$.

As you know, the last digit of $k^n$ is periodic in $n$ for every $k$. Let $T(k)$ be the period length

Typically, the last digit of $k^n$ has a period like $$[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_i]$$.

For example, $4^n$ has a period 
$$[4,6]$$ and $T(4)=2$.

$7^n$ has a period $$[7,9,3,1]$$ and $T(7)=4$.

So, just find the remainder of $b^c$ divided by $T(k)$. Let the remainder be $r$. Then the $r$th term in the period is the last digit of $a^{b^c}$. $r=0$ implies the last term.

---

Finding $r$ is not easy if $b,c$ are large.

Let $r’$ be the remainder of $b$ divided by $T(k)$.

Let $R$ be the remainder of $r’^c$ divided by $T(k)$.

It can be shown that $R=r$.

Since $r’$ is small, computing $R$ is more manageable and doable by hand.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. Very clearly explained :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to find what $a^{b^c}$ is modulo $10$. To do this, it's enough to find what it is modulo $2$ and then modulo $5$: by the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), $(n\bmod 2, n\bmod 5)$ contains exactly as much information as $n\bmod 10$: $$\matrix{n\bmod 2&n\bmod 5&n\bmod 10\\0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&2&2\\1&3&3\\0&4&4\\1&0&5\\0&1&6\\1&2&7\\0&3&8\\1&4&9}$$

- $a^{b^c}\bmod 2$ is the parity of the last digit of $a$ (since $0$ to any power stays $0$ and the same for $1$).
- $a^{b^c}\bmod 5$ is $0$ if $a\equiv 0\bmod 5$
- if $a\not \equiv 0\bmod 5$ to compute $a^{b^c}\bmod 5$ you can apply Fermat's Little Theorem: $$a^4\equiv 1\bmod 5$$
  and the problem reduces to find $b^c\bmod 4$. This depends only on what $b$ is modulo $4$, and what $c$ is modulo $2$ since all geometric sequences modulo $4$ have period $1$ or $2$. Therefore, you can replace $b$ by its remainder $b'$ in the division by $4$, and $c$ by its parity $c'$ ($0$ if $c$ is even, $1$ otherwise)

  Finally, $a^{b^c}\bmod 5$ is equal to $(a')^{(b')^{c'}}$ where $a'$ is the remainder in the division of $a$ by $5$.